# Adding document with certain ID without overwriting existing one

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a document with my custom unique ID to Firestore, so set() seems to be the way, given add() will auto generate an ID.
What I want, is to get an error if I add a new document with an existing ID.

So, I want to add myObj, and I want the id of the document to be myObj.id:

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc(myObj.code)
    .set(myObj)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('SENT!');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    })
```

But when I add a new document with an existing ID, instead of getting an error, it overwrites it.

I thought about using the DB rules, but it's still not quite clear to me. I will need to deny just that operation, but if I want to update a field of certain document, I should be able to do that.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update following your comment**:

Your requirement is "I want to add a new document with the ID: '1A2b3Cd' if it doesn't exist, and if it exists and I try to add a new document with the ID: '1A2b3Cd', I want to get an error."

I think the best would be to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction) as follows:

```
var docRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc(myObj.code);

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            throw "Document already exists!";
        }

        transaction.set(docRef, myObj);
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

As detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set), with the `set()` method, "if the document does not exist yet, it will be created".

---

If you want to "update a field of certain *(existing)* document" you should provide a [`SetOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions) object with `merge: true` to the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method, as follows (excerpt of the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)):

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
    capital: true
}, { merge: true });
```

So, in your case:

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).doc(myObj.code)
    .set(myObj, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('SENT!');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    })
```

Note that the difference with the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method is that, with `update()`, "the update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist".

Comment: Sorry, may be I wasn't clear? I don't want to add new data to a document. I want to add a new document with the ID: '1A2b3Cd' if it doesn't exist, and if it exists and I try to add a new document with the ID: '1A2b3Cd', I want to get an error. Suggested 'merge: true' and 'update()' don't accomplish what I need at all.

Comment: Thank you @Renaud for both of your answers, and really sorry for the late reply. I just tried your solution and work great. The thing is, one will have to make a GET before each SET, for each insertion, and I believe, as you did, that it's better to do that inside a transaction rather tan outside. Is this the only way? Is this a "flaw" from Firestore?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will accept it of course. It solved my problem, and I can't find any other way to do that. Cheers!